# Aligning object in Graphic

Tags: graphics, inset

When I try putting dot graph(ListPlot) named dg as below to my Histogram graphic.The horizental axis is not exactly aligned. How to fix my code?

```
dg = ListPlot[{Transpose[{{0.66, -0.09}, ConstantArray[0.1, i]}]}, 
  PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> {{-6, 6}, {0, 5}}, 
  PlotRangePadding -> {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}]
```

[image]

```
(*How to fix code?*)    
Histogram[{0.66, -0.09}, PlotRange -> {{-6, 6}, Automatic},
     Epilog -> {Inset[dg, Scaled@{0, 0}, Scaled@{0, 0}, Scaled[1]]},
     PlotRangePadding -> {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Use `Show` to combine the two plots, rather than an Inset. `Show[{Histogram[...], dg}]` after removing the `Epilog` from `Histrogram`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### 1. Using Epilog + Inset

1. Use the same `ImagePadding` (say `ImagePadding -> 20`) in `ListPlot` and `Histogram`.
2. Use [ImageScaled](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageScaled.html) to specify *size* (the fourth argument) in `Inset[...]`.

```
dg = ListPlot[{Transpose[{{0.66, -0.09}, ConstantArray[0.1, 2]}]}, 
   PlotStyle -> Red, 
   PlotRange -> {{-6, 6}, {0, 5}}, 
   PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
   ImagePadding -> 20];

Histogram[{0.66, -0.09}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-6, 6}, Automatic}, 
 Epilog -> {Inset[dg, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, ImageScaled[1]]}, 
 PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
 ImagePadding -> 20]
```

[image]

In this case, `Inset[dg, Scaled@{0, 0}, Scaled@{0, 0}, ImageScaled[1]]` gives the same result.

Add the option `AxesOrigin -> {3,0}` in `Histogram[...]` to show two vertical axes:

[image]

**See:**

- [`Scaled`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Scaled.html)
- [`ImageScaled`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageScaled.html)
- [`Inset`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inset.html)

#### 2. Epilog only

An easier approach is to avoid the alignment issue using graphics primitives from `dg` (that, is `dg[[1]]`) as the option value for `Epilog` and, if needed, modify the vertical tick labels using `` Charting`FindTicks ``.

```
Histogram[{0.66, -0.09}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-6, 6}, Automatic}, 
 Epilog -> {dg[[1]]}, 
 PlotRangePadding -> 0
 Ticks -> {Automatic, Charting`FindTicks[{0, 1}, {0, 5}]}, 
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image]

#### 3. Show

Combine `dg` and histogram using `Show` as suggested by MarcoB in comments; and, if needed, modify the vertical tick labels:

```
Show[Histogram[{0.66, -0.09}, PlotRange -> {{-6, 6}, Automatic}, 
  PlotRangePadding -> 0], dg, 
 Ticks -> {Automatic, Charting`FindTicks[{0, 1}, {0, 5}]}, 
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image]